# Not a JPEG file: Starts with 0x6c 0x85

Tags: image, jpeg

I am trying to open JPG files but the error i get is Not a JPEG file: Starts with 0x6c 0x85

What filetype is that? I am using Windows 10 and i got those error messages out of GIMP.

Tried searching through the web but couldnt find 0x6c 0x85...

Comment: Can you share this file?

Comment: The file is too large to upload. It's 6MB..

Comment: Then show the output of `od -c file.jpg | head`.

Comment: These are the last few lines

006A7B60   98 25 78 78 67 9F 7A 8F F9 A8 D4 89 31 AF EF B4  %xxgzù¨Ô1¯ï´
006A7B70   47 73 3E A8 7B 73 8A 5F 0F 5F AF 8C 93 78 3D 7C  Gs>¨{s_._¯x=|
006A7B80   23 FF 02 36 82 06 80 4B CD E1 03 36 AC 9C 1E D0  #..6.KÍá.6¬.Ð
006A7B90   4D E8 2E 98 5D C2 30 00 5D 35 67 AA 98 36 6A 7C  Mè.]Â0.]5gª6j|
006A7BA0   85 55 2F 55 9B AC B5 19 E9 EE 8A 49 89 E8 7F 9E  U/Uµ.éîIè⌂
006A7BB0   93 FC 92 01 67 2D 89 6F 3B 81 7F CF 0E 49 90 61  ü.g-o;⌂Ï.Ia
006A7BC0   DC 4F 64 19 1D                                   ÜOd..

Comment: You forgot the "`| head`". The output must start with `0000000`.

Comment: 00000000   6C 85 86 B1 67 0A D2 10 6F DE 01 E7 98 FA 44 AD  l±g.Ò.oÞ.çúD­
00000010   AA 3A A0 A2 D0 92 00 CA CA 04 BC 45 31 62 47 E6  ª: ¢Ð.ÊÊ.¼E1bGæ
00000020   5B DA BE 96 3F AE 9F 51 73 50 E8 1D D4 14 9A 5A  [Ú¾?®QsPè.Ô.Z
00000030   E7 BE 58 A1 79 AF 45 31 B8 95 81 85 37 E4 9E 5C  ç¾X¡y¯E1¸7ä\
00000040   ED 5C D5 01 54 E4 35 B2 26 7C 32 BC 93 D1 82 4B  í\Õ.Tä5²&|2¼ÑK

Comment: Hmm, it's definitely not a JPEG file. Maybe it's encrypted somehow.

Comment: Another thing to try is `strings YOURFILE` to see if there are any recognisable words. And `file YOURFILE` to see if your OS can work it out.

Comment: I dont have linux near me.. Im afraid i cannot run those commands